# Linux + files & folders cleanup under /tmp

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron, services, tmp

On all my Red Hat Linux machines version 7.2 we saw that systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service is inactive:

```
systemctl status systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
● systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service - Cleanup of Temporary Directories
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2018-12-19 14:47:14 UTC; 12min ago
     Docs: man:tmpfiles.d(5)
           man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)
  Process: 34231 ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --clean (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 34231 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 19 14:47:14 master02.uridns.com systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Dec 19 14:47:14 master02.uridns.com systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
```

It is strange that we saw the files and folders under `/tmp`,
and it seems that cleanup is performed every some time.

I searched on crontab or cronjob, but I did not find other cleanup jobs.

Am I missing something here?

Is it possible that in spite of the service being inactive, the cleanup is performed every couple of weeks?

```
  systemctl enable  systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service

The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
```

We also saw a few folders that were real old, as

```
ls -ltr
total 137452
drwxr-xr-x 3 root      root         33 Jun 13  2017 Tools
drwx--x--x 3 root      root         16 Oct 12 09:33 systemd-private-74982d8a24254a1d8b8ec3b5c0d80a9b-httpd.service-QZqGLA
drwx--x--x 3 root      root         16 Oct 12 10:02 systemd-private-74982d8a24254a1d8b8ec3b5c0d80a9b-rtkit-daemon.service-BTcGY1
drwx--x--x 3 root      root         16 Oct 12 10:02 systemd-private-74982d8a24254a1d8b8ec3b5c0d80a9b-vmtoolsd.service-mQ1SXc
drwxr-xr-x 2 ambari    ambari       18 Oct 12 12:02 hsperfdata_ambari
drwx--x--x 3 root      root         16 Oct 12 12:17 systemd-private-74982d8a24254a1d8b8ec3b5c0d80a9b-cups.service-PnKaq8
drwx--x--x 3 root      root         16 Oct 12 12:17 systemd-private-74982d8a24254a1d8b8ec3b5c0d80a9b-colord.service-DNn470
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root      root      83044 Nov 18 17:27 Spark_Thrift.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 zookeeper hadoop       18 Nov 18 17:28 hsperfdata_zookeeper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root      root        379 Nov 18 17:37 requests.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root      root     137348 Nov 22 14:50 pp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root      root        344 Nov 26 15:24 yy
prwx--x--x 1 root      root          0 Nov 29 21:26 hogsuspend
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root      root       1032 Dec  3 10:55 aa
```

From my machine:

```
more /lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories
Documentation=man:tmpfiles.d(5) man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)

[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=1d
```

**The rules are:**

```
more /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

# See tmpfiles.d(5) for details

# Clear tmp directories separately, to make them easier to override
v /tmp 1777 root root 10d
v /var/tmp 1777 root root 30d

# Exclude namespace mountpoints created with PrivateTmp=yes
x /tmp/systemd-private-%b-*
X /tmp/systemd-private-%b-*/tmp
x /var/tmp/systemd-private-%b-*
X /var/tmp/systemd-private-%b-*/tmp
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can ask systemd what a unit’s triggers are:

```
systemctl show -p TriggeredBy systemd-tmpfiles-clean
```

This will show that the `systemd-tmpfiles-clean` service is triggered by the `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer` timer. That is defined as

```
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories
Documentation=man:tmpfiles.d(5) man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)

[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=1d
```

Thus the service runs every day, and cleans directories up based on the `tmpfiles.d` configuration. See the associated man pages for details.

Comment: I update my question see the - "we can saw also few folder that real old as"  , so if service is up evry 24Hours the how it can be that we have older files ?

Comment: How often the service runs is one thing, what the deletion criteria are is another. See the last part of my answer.

Comment: I post also the rules , as you can see some files and folder are not defined in the rules , and in spite this they are not deleted ?

Comment: as you can see from the rules - /tmp 1777 root root 10d , its mean that files or folder that old then 10day will be deleted but for example - Tools is older folder or hsperfdata_ambari , so how it can be ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Your `ls` output shows the last modification time, but the last access time is also taken into account, as is the status change time for files.

Comment: about - "v /tmp 1777 root root 10d"   , since we are talking here about /tmp can we set it to - v /tmp 1777 root root 1d  , so each 24Hours all files that are older then 1d will be deleted ?

Comment: or can we set the - OnUnitActiveSec to OnUnitActiveSec=1h and "v /tmp 1777 root root 1d   ?

Comment: That’s another question.

Comment: so in that case can I post a new question please ?

Comment: Yes, please do that.

Comment: see my post on - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489956/how-to-manage-cleaning-of-tmp-better

Comment: It's worth noting that the answer to "despite the service being inactive" is in the question, where it tells one that the service was last active 12 minutes ago.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt   ,  just to come to say thank you for all , you are the best here

Answer (score 6):

`systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service` is initiated by `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer`. You can inspect the timers with `systemctl list-timers`.

At least on Ubuntu 16.04, the `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer` is defined as

```
# Use `systemctl cat systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer` to get your corresponding file
#
# /lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
[Unit]
Description=Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories
Documentation=man:tmpfiles.d(5) man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)

[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=1d
```

Therefore, the timer will start `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service` 15 minutes after boot, and every 24 hours afterwards.

For more information, see `systemd.timer(5)`, `systemd.service(5)` and `systemd.unit(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with most descriptions here is that they do not include how it can be used to delete not just files but folders, and all subfolders inside the folder including files:

e.g. `/home/user/.cache/`: How would you be able to tell the tool to delete all folders in `/.cache/folder1/subfolder1` & `folder2/subfolder1` etc.?

It gives me an error stating folders are not empty when executing command `/.cache/*` for example:

```
# Delete User Space Temp Files
r /home/user/.cache/*
```

Excecuting:

```
# env SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug systemd-tmpfiles --remove
```

shows the errors and doesn't actually delete anythinge except files in that top folder.