# how to manage cleaning of /tmp better on hadoop machines

Tags: linux, rhel, cron, services, hadoop

As all know the content of /tmp should be deleted after some time.

In my case we have machines ( redhat version 7.2 )  that are configured as following.

As we can see the service that is triggered to clean up `/tmp` will be activated every 24H ( 1d ).

`systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer` from my machine:

```
more /lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories
Documentation=man:tmpfiles.d(5) man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)

[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=1d
```

And this is the file that is responsible for the rules.
We can see that files/folders according to these rules will be deleted if they are older then  10 days, (this is my understanding , please correct me if I am wrong).

**the rules are:**

```
more /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

# See tmpfiles.d(5) for details

# Clear tmp directories separately, to make them easier to override
v /tmp 1777 root root 10d
v /var/tmp 1777 root root 30d

# Exclude namespace mountpoints created with PrivateTmp=yes
x /tmp/systemd-private-%b-*
X /tmp/systemd-private-%b-*/tmp
x /var/tmp/systemd-private-%b-*
X /var/tmp/systemd-private-%b-*/tmp
```

But because we have a hadoop cluster, we noticed that `/tmp` contains thousands of empty folders and files, and also folders and files with content that are really huge.

Example:

```
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 13:54 2d069b18-f07f-4c8b-a7c7-45cd8cfc9d42_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 13:59 ed46a2a0-f142-4bff-9a7b-f2d430aff26d_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 14:04 ce7dc2ca-7a12-4aca-a4ef-87803a33a353_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 14:09 43fd3ce0-01f0-423a-89e5-cfd9f82792e6_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 14:14 f808fe5b-2f27-403f-9704-5d53cba176d3_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 14:19 6ef04ca4-9ab1-43f3-979c-9ba5edb9ccee_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 14:24 387330de-c6f5-4055-9f43-f67d577bd0ed_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 14:29 9517d4d9-8964-41c1-abde-a85f226b38ea_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 14:34 a46a9083-f097-4460-916f-e431f5790bf8_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 14:39 81379a84-17c8-4b24-b69a-d91710868560_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 14:44 4b8ba746-12f5-4caf-b21e-52300b8712a5_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 14:49 b7a2f98b-ecf2-4e9c-a92f-0da31d12a81a_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 14:54 2a745ade-e1a7-421d-9829-c7eb915982ce_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 14:59 9dc1a021-9adf-448b-856d-b14e2cb9812b_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 15:04 5599580d-c664-4f2e-95d3-ebdf479a33b9_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 15:09 d97dfbb5-444a-4401-ba58-d338f1724e68_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 15:14 832cf420-f601-4549-b131-b08853339a39_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 15:19 cd1f10e2-ad4e-4b4e-a3cb-4926ccc5a9c5_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 15:24 19dff3c0-8024-4631-b8da-1d31fea7203f_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 15:29 23528426-b8fb-4d14-8ea9-2fb799fefe51_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 15:34 e3509760-9823-4e30-8d0b-77c5aee80efd_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 15:39 3c157b4d-917c-49ef-86da-b44e310ca30a_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 15:44 b370af30-5323-4ad5-b39e-f02a0dcdc6bb_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 15:49 18a5ea21-30f9-45a8-8774-6d8200ada7ff_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 15:54 ee776a04-f0e8-4295-9872-f8fc6482913e_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 15:59 f5935653-0bf6-4171-895a-558eef8b0773_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 16:04 e80ea30b-c729-48a2-897d-ae7c94a4fa04_resources
drwx------    2 hive      hadoop      6 Dec 19 16:09 fde6f7e4-89bd-41b4-99d3-17204bf66f05_resources
```

We are worried that `/tmp` will be full and services can't delete the content because of that.

So we want to delete the folders and files from `/tmp` according to this:

**every folder/file will be deleted if it is older than 1 day**

**and service will be activated each 1 hour**

So we intend to set the following:

```
OnUnitActiveSec=1h    ( in file /lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer )

v /tmp 1777 root root 1d (  in file /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf )
```

Am I right here with the new settings?

***secondly - after setting this, do we need to do something for it to take effect ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This combination will certainly work. However, instead of removing all in `/tmp` every hour, you're probably better of by deleting the resource files and directories only, e.g.

```
R /tmp/*_resources
```

Keep in mind that your changes on the systemd and tmpfiles configuration should ***not*** be done in `/usr` or `/lib`. Instead, place the according overrides in `/etc`, e.g.

```
echo 'R /tmp/*_resources' >> /etc/tmpfiles.d/hadoop
cp /lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer \
   /etc/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
$EDITOR /etc/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
```

If you change the files in `/usr` or `/lib` you might end up with conflicts during upgrades.

---

If you already changed your files, make sure to reload the unit files with `systemctl daemon-reload`. Otherwise `systemd` won't pickup the change of your timer.

Comment: lets say I set OnUnitActiveSec=1h     wand " v /tmp 1777 root root 1d " , how to take affect this configuration ?

Comment: I also update this note in my post

Comment: I am posting new question regarding that

Comment: @yael you essentially changed your question so much that you've asked a new one. Please refrain from changing the original aspect of a question in the future. Either way, I guess you didn't `daemon-reload` your configuration yet.

Comment: what you mean about daemon-reload , and how to do that?

Comment: See my [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/489963/revisions). Also see `man systemctl` and `man systemd`, if you haven't read systemd's documentation yet.

Comment: ok , I run the systemctl daemon-reload on all our machines that are with the new setting , lets see if /tmp will be with only the files of today

Comment: by the way after we run the daemon-reload , how much time we need to wait , according my new settings  ?

Comment: As I already said in my last answer, look at `systemctl list-timers`. Please read the documentation of the tools you use. Many of the questions you ask are already handed by the docs. Furthermore if you really changed `/lib` and `/usr` files, your systems might be in a semi-broken state, aka they might report file conflicts during an upgrade. Have a look at `man hier` for more information.